# "Lookup Product" Use case for a project due tonight

Tags: uml, use-case

I've only used Stackoverflow for programming questions but I can't think of anywhere else to go for this.

I have a couple use cases I need to do by tonight and I'm stuck on my first one because my professor says the Activity Flow is wrong because the actor needs at least more than 1 activity, but for this particular case I cannot think of anything else, I literally spent hours scratching my head.

I'd greatly appreciate insight into this because I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Austen

[image]

Comment: Instead of stating *I have an urgent project to do* (this won't make anybody here), pick better tags and title -- this will increase chances of this question.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yeah, no need to be like that, I didn't have enough rep to use the tag use case so I had to do that. That is now corrected.

Comment: well, I don't mean to be rude, just saying that most people out there, who usually answer questions are either subscribed to a specific tags, or skim through the questions stream and descriptive, clear title encourage people to read question body. On the other hand, *Due tonight*, *Help ASAP* and the like do not increase number of people who can potentially help you.

Comment: I understand that, Stackoverflow moves very quickly; I'm not the best when it comes to title picking :P

Answer (score 2):

An obvious one I can think of is "Customer presses search button to process search" or something to that effect. You mention the search button in your use case but nothing is really done with it after you mention it.

Comment: Thank you! That is so silly of me to forget that! I'll include that, but apparently it's not good enough somehow... My professor is very picky even though the course is called "Software Engineering Methodologies "1"" He actually got rude when I showed him that, telling me I might as well not have even come to class, pft.

Comment: Here's a link that may provide you with a bit more insight into the scope of your project. You can also use the arrows on the page to navigate to the other steps of course. http://www.cragsystems.co.uk/use_case_tutorial/act01/06act01.htm